# Draw img with iced Rust

Tags: user-interface, graphics, rust

I start to dev in Rust and I want to dev graphical interface for print picture.
My problem is for draw img with this lib. Doc is used https://docs.rs/iced/0.1.1/iced/widget/image/struct.Image.html

So you can watch my code below :

```
use iced::*;

pub struct GeoRust;

impl Application for GeoRust {
    type Executor = executor::Null;
    type Message = ();
    type Flags = ();

    fn new(_flags: ()) -> (GeoRust, Command<Self::Message>) {
        (GeoRust, Command::none())
    }

    fn title(&self) -> String {
        String::from("GeoRust")
    }

    fn update(&mut self, _message: Self::Message) -> Command<Self::Message> {
        let img = widget::image::Image::new("./data/dataGetLegendGraphic.png");
        img.draw(renderer: &mut Renderer, _defaults: &Renderer::Defaults, layout: Layout<'_>, _cursor_position: Point);
        Command::none()
    }

    fn view(&mut self) -> Element<Self::Message> {
        Text::new("GeoRust, world!").into()
    }
}
```

and I don't know what to put as a parameter. I don't see everything or I can find that in the lib.

And if you have time I don't know how to put variable in GeoRust struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to enable the `image` feature as is listed in the [documentation for `0.1.1`](https://docs.rs/iced/0.1.1/iced/widget/image/struct.Image.html).

**cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
iced = { version = "0.1", features = ["image"] }
```

Given the following working directory:

```
.  iced_stackoverflow
├─ Cargo.lock
├─ Cargo.toml
├─ resources/
│  └─ ferris.png
├─ src/
│  └─ main.rs
└─ target/
```

We can create a full sized image with the following code:

**src/main.rs**

```rust
use iced::{executor, Application, Command, Container, Element, Image, Length, Settings};

fn main() {
    Example::run(Settings::default());
}

struct Example;

impl Application for Example {
    type Executor = executor::Null;
    type Message = ();
    type Flags = ();

    fn new(_flags: ()) -> (Example, Command<Self::Message>) {
        (Example, Command::none())
    }

    fn title(&self) -> String {
        String::from("Example application")
    }

    fn update(&mut self, _message: Self::Message) -> Command<Self::Message> {
        Command::none()
    }

    fn view(&mut self) -> Element<Self::Message> {
        let image = Image::new("resources/ferris.png")
            .width(Length::Fill)
            .height(Length::Fill);

        Container::new(image)
            .width(Length::Fill)
            .height(Length::Fill)
            .center_x()
            .center_y()
            .into()
    }
}
```

Which will give us the following application:

[image: Screenshot of the Iced application with an image of Ferris]

There are also many [examples](https://github.com/hecrj/iced/tree/3f44d331d9c7afe14416130f54abd2b327a686bf/examples) in the `Iced` repository one can learn from.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. And if I want to add var at my struct I error in new method

expected value, found struct `GeoRust`

Comment: What specifically would you like to add to the `Struct`?

Comment: i want to add src: String where I save the path of my png

Comment: I think you will have to use a separate `Struct` other than the one that takes the `impl` of `Application`, i.e. `Example` or `GeoStruct`.


You could then use something like ```struct GeoImage { src: String }```.

Comment: this is an awesome answer! What would make the answer even more complete is, if you were to include (a) how to set the image from "fn main" and how to update it thereafter.